# Computing derivatives for backpropagation across a convolution step

Tags: convolution, neural-networks

This will be a long post, but I hope it'll be instructive to anyone else in my position. I'm trying to find how the derivatives of the loss function are calculated with respect to the kernels and intermediate outputs of convolution layers. Here's the simple setup I'm going with for now:

For practical purposes, I've heard we generally use cross-correlation, so my entire treatment of the problem is based around that. Let $I$ be an $m\times n$ image (or an intermediate conv layer output) on which a $p\times q$ filter $K$ is used to produce output $O$. **Starting out, I'm only considering *valid* cross-correlation performed on $I$**, which means no padding. We then have:

$$O(i,j)=(I\star K) (i,j)=\sum_{u=1}^p\sum_{v=1}^qI(i+u-1,j+v-1)K(u,v)$$

where $\star$ means cross-correlation. Let $dX$ generally denote the derivative of the loss function w.r.t. the quantity $X$. Then
$$dK(u',v') = \sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}dO_{ij}\frac{\partial O_{ij}}{\partial K(u',v')}
\\=\sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}dO(i,j)I(i+u'-1,j+v'-1)
\\=\sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}I(u'+i-1,v'+j-1)dO(i,j) = (I\star dO)(u',v')
\\\implies dK = I\star dO$$

To find $dI$, first I can apply a change of variables to the formula for $O(i,j)$. Let $i'=i+u-1$ and $j'=j+v-1$. Corresponding to the summation limits $u=1$ and $u=p$, we have $i'=i$ and $i'=i+p-1.$ Similarly for $v$ and $j'$. We get:

$$O(i,j)=\sum_{i'=i}^{i+p-1}\sum_{j'=j}^{j+q-1}K(i'-i+1,j'-j+1)I(i',j')$$

Then
$$dI(i'',j'')=\sum_{i=1}^{m-p+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-q+1}dO_{ij}\frac{\partial O_{ij}}{\partial I(i'',j'')}$$

Note that there will be values of $i,j$ such that $i''< i$ and/or $j''<j$ in which case the derivative $O(i,j)$ w.r.t. $I(i'',j'')$ will be zero (since the summation indices $i',j'$ in the formula for $O(i,j)$ above will start from $i,j$ respectively and won't equal $i'',j''$).

So at this point I'm stuck. **Can anyone help me out from this point on, to derive the expression for $dI$? I worked through the specific case where $m=n=4$ and $p=q=2$. In that case, it turns out that $dI=dO*K'$, where $*$ denotes *full* cross-correlation with zero-padding and $K'$ is the transposed (flipped) version of $K$. But how do I deal with the problem of indices $i'',j''$ going out of bounds in the above equations? Is there an alternative approach?**

---

Secondly, how are the formulas for $dK$ and $dI$ generalized to the case when stride $=2$ ? Again, I worked out for the specific case $m=n=4$ and $p=q=2$ as follows:

Let the stride in the $x$ ($y$) direction be $s_x$ ($s_y$). Then

$$O(i,j)=\sum_{u,v=1}^2K(u,v)I((i-1)s_y+u,(j-1)s_x+v)$$

(You can check the above formula yourself) Then

$$dK(u',v')=\sum_{i,j=1}^2dO(i,j)I(u'+(i-1)s_y,v'+(j-1)s_x)$$

I don't see any easy way of writing this in the form of a cross-correlation formula. For example, if $s_x=s_y=2$,

$$dK(2,1)=dO(1,1)I(2,1)+dO(1,2)I(2,3)+dO(2,1)I(4,1)+dO(2,2)I(4,3)$$

[image]

How does one efficiently implement an operation like this? Not to mention I haven't even touched upon what $dI$ looks like with strides greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the ordinary case involves the transpose of the matrix of weights, the convolutional case involves the adjoint of cross correlation by  the kernal $K$, which in the strided case may be neither a convolution not a cross correlation. Computing this for your case of $2D$ images will require using two indices each for $I$, $O$, and $K$, separated by a comma. There are additionally stride parameters $s$ and $t$. It sounds like you're padding with zeros, so we can interpret all out-of bounds values of $O$ and $I$ as fixed at zero. The shape of the kernel is implicit in the allowed values of indices. I'll be indexing $K$ and $M$ based on offset, so indices can be negative or zero.
$$
O_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}I_{si+k,tj+l}K_{k,l}=I\star K
$$
The first backprop formula is a matter applying chain rule as before. The result is essentially a strided cross correlation, where the striding is understood to apply to the dummy index on the second argument, and all arrays are padded by zeros.
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial K_{k,l}}=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial C}{\partial O_{i,j}}I_{k+si,l+tj},\ \ \ \frac{\partial C}{\partial K}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial O}\star_{s,t}I
$$
The second formula requires resolving some Kronecker deltas, which results in somthing which could be interpreted as a strided convolution, where the striding is understood to apply to the dummy index on the second argument.
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial I_{k,l}}=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial C}{\partial O_{i,j}}K_{k-si,l-tj},\ \ \ \frac{\partial C}{\partial I}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial O}*_{s,t}K
$$
When padding the boundaries, all you have to do is restrict the sums in the above formulas so as not to go out of bounds. For instance, for an input indexed by $[1,M]\times[1,N]$ and a kernel indexed by offsets $[p,p']\times[q,q']$, with strides $s, t$ and an output indexed by [$1,A]\times[1,B]$, these would be
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial K_{k,l}}=\sum_{i\in[1,A] \\ k+si\in[1,M]}\ \ \ \sum_{j\in[1,B] \\ l+tj\in[1,N]}\frac{\partial C}{\partial O_{i,j}}I_{k+si,l+tj},\ \ \ k\in[p,p'],\ l\in[q,q']
$$
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial I_{k,l}}=\sum_{i\in[1,A] \\ k-si\in[p,p']}\ \ \ \sum_{j\in[1,B] \\ l-tj\in[q,q']}\frac{\partial C}{\partial O_{i,j}}K_{k-si,l-tj},\ \ \ k\in[1,A],\ l\in[1,B]
$$
How best to implement these depends on context; if you have cross-correlation/convolution with appropriate padding/restrictions and striding options, they should work fine. Otherwise in may be necessary to implement the sums directly. Of course, different methods of handling boundaries will require different restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm afraid I don't follow some of the convention you've written. e.g. of what I didn't exactly understand: "shape of the kernel can be encoded in a mask $M_{kl}$". I don't understand the concept of using a mask. Could you please elaborate? (if at all possible, via a concrete example of say $4\times 4$ image and $2\times 2$ kernel). I also don't understand the symbol $\star_{s,t}$. Sorry for the trouble but I'm a beginner to all this and the indexing convention I use just follows how matrices are implemented in a programming language ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... Not saying you use my exact convention but it'd be super helpful if you could explain a bit more of the concept/convention you're using, as you would to a beginner. It will enable me to follow along to what you've written. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not really necessary; just a way of encoding the indices on which the kernel is allowed to take nonzero values. I've removed it and left the kernel indices implicit.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the calculations to arrive at the formula for $dI$ (which involves resolving Kronecker deltas - I'm not familiar with the concept)

Comment: Basically it's just computing the derivative $\frac{\partial O_{i,j}}{\partial I_{k,l}}$
$$
\frac{\partial O_{i,j}}{\partial I_{k,l}}=\sum_{a,b}I_{si+a,tj+b}\frac{\partial K_{a,b}}{\partial K_{k,l}}
$$
$$
=\sum_{a,b}I_{si+a,tj+b}\delta_{a,k}\delta_{b,l}
$$
$$
=I_{si+k,tj+l}
$$

Comment: So I tried out a 1-D example for finding $dI$ with stride = $2$. Let's say you have a 1D image $I$ of length $14$ and a kernel $K$ of length $4$. Then the output of a stride $2$ cross-correlation of $I$ with $K$ will be $O$ with length $6$. Now to get $dI$, it turned out that we can take $dO$ and "spread it out" by inserting a single zero-element between each of its existing elements, so that it's new length will be $11$. Then pad it on both sides with $3$ (length of $K$ minus $1$) zeros. e.g. if earlier it was $1-4-2-6-8-4$, it would now become $0-0-0-1-0-4-0-2-0-6-0-8-0-4-0-0-0$...

Comment: ... and denote this transformed version of $dO$ by $dO'$. Flip the kernel to get $K'$. Then $dI$ is the cross-corr of $dO'$ & $K'$. The number of zeros inserted between the elements of $dO$ would depend on the stride length. Assuming indexing from $0$ to (length $-1$), the formula is $dI(i)=\sum_{u=0}^{\dim(K)-1}K'(u)dO'(i+u+1-\dim(K))$ (out of bounds indices are assigned $0$). This is not a rigorous proof and involves modifying $dO$ to arrive at a proper cross-corr formulation. Can't think of any elegant way to formulate it with vanilla $dO$ and $K$. What do you think? Does this seem correct?

Comment: As long as you're using striding, there will be cases where the adjoint is not a convolution/cross correlation because the kernel is not consistent between pixels. Consider (in 1D) a kernel of size 3 with stride 2: going forward, every output is computed from 3 inputs. Going backward, however, some inputs affect one output while others affect two (not translation invariant).

It looks like what you're doing there is "removing" the striding by creating extra outputs such that the stride is 1, and then setting all but the ones you want to zero.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. My reason is because I've read that convolution/cross-correlation operations are implemented really efficiently on GPUs, so maybe it'd be worth it to translate it into a form that resembles standard full cross-correlation. Plus, it makes things a bit more intuitively clear, at least for me.